# Electron Secure Mysql Credentials

Tags: electron

I've been hungry for a long time to connect to the mysql database so that the user can not see the password. I do not know how to do it. I've been reading articles, here, but nowhere.
How does this, for example, make a discord? Which is connected to the mysql database, and yet the user can not see the password?

Answer (score 1):

You should not connect directly to a database from the client application that the user runs. Instead you should create an API that requires authentication that the clients application can call.